# How to run AngularJS 1 app locally using Node js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, localserver

I worked with Angular 2+ app where I serve index.html file from the dist folder using node js server like this

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.get('*'), (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
};

app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    res.send('It worked!!!');
});

app.listen(5000);
console.log('Server is running');
```

It worked very well for me with Angular 2+ apps, but when I tried same thing for AngularJS 1 app, its not working well for me

I have some local files links in the index.html something like this

```
<script src="components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js">
```

where components folder is bower folder which is inside dist folder itself. but this file is not able to serve on localhost, its throwing 404 for this file.

I am trying this all to mock the api call, so that I can serve mock json data from my local, It will be very helpful if anyone finds what wrong I am doing here,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I think is the issue with the path you have mentioned in index.html.
Looks like bower config file is getting ignored. Can you try putting the full path (e.g. bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js).

Let me know if it works.

Thanks

Comment: I tried your idea like I changed path to <script src="../components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"> and it worked fine, but the thing is I have around 30 local file links in the index.html file, so whenerver I build the app, I need to change the path each time, coz those links generates when I run grunt build, So  is there any better solution in my node js code itself?